Edit geometry of a model in a new pose
I'm familiar with the concepts of reference poses etc., but I'm not quite sure how to achieve what I need in Blender for this specific situation.
I've decompiled a model from an old game and want to add some extra geometry to it. This specific model is a turret within a fold-out briefcase, and in its default reference pose the briefcase is closed, so this makes it difficult to add anything.

If I import the deployed-idle animation then the briefcase is opened, which makes life much easier.

However, if I go back to edit mode after having imported this animation, the geometry resets to being closed again.
I have tried applying the open pose using Object -> Apply -> Visual Geometry to Mesh. This means that the briefcase does stay open in edit mode, but it also means that if I then go into pose mode, moving bones no longer affects the model. I'm assuming this would mean I'd have to re-skin the model to the bones, which I'm reluctant to do just yet without properly understanding what's going on here.
I'd like to be able to add geometry to the model while it's in the open pose, without losing the original closed reference pose. This is because the other animations for the model will expect the original closed reference pose to be maintained, and I don't want to break them. Is there a way to do this? Alternatively, if I do use the Apply -> Visual Geometry to Mesh method above, is there a way to revert this so that I can re-export the geometry in the closed pose?

A good number of months later, I stumbled across the solution.
Edit a rigged mesh in pose position? implies the Adjust Edit Cage to Modifier Result button is what I wanted, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the settings. Turns out these settings are hidden until you click the modifier button, and I was then able to change them.

